# How can I mix the method so that all factors are display? I am missing one more factor

Tags: java, methods

```
    public static String factorX(long x){
        String factor="";
        long number = x;
        long i = 2;  
        while (i < number) {  
                if (number % i == 0) {
                factor += i+", "; 
                number /= i;

            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return factor; 

For example if I put 120, i get 2,2,2,3. I am missing factor 5. Everything else works find;
```

is just that thing that is not displayed.....................................................................

Comment: Change the `while` loop condition to `i <= number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
while (i < number) {
```

to:

```
while (i <= number) {
```

and you're good to go. However, this wouldn't print 1 or 2 as the prime factors of the numbers 1 and 2, respectively. So you might want to add something like this as well:

```
    if(x < 2) {
        return "" + x;
    }
    return factor;
```

Comment: Now works I was just missing that, thanks. Why is it I need the =?

Comment: @user3304653 It's because you divided 120 down to 5, then your loop checked if `i<5` where i=5. 5<5 is false, as they're equal, so the loop exited.